# Generating "Fake" Records Within A Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very basic statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT pet, animal_type, number_of_legs 
FROM table
```

However, where `table` currently is, I want to insert some fake data, along the lines of:

```
rufus       cat     3
franklin    turtle  1
norm        dog     5
```

Is it possible to "generate" these fake records, associating each value with the corresponding field, from within a query so that they are returned as the result of the query?

Comment: All those poor disfigured animals!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT pet, animal_type, number_of_legs FROM table
union select 'rufus',    'cat',    3
union select 'franklin', 'turtle', 1
union select 'norm',     'dog',    5
```

This gives you the content of `table` plus the 3 records you want, avoiding duplicates, if duplicates are OK, then replace `union` with `union all`

edit: per your comment, for tsql, you can do:

```
select top 110 'franklin', 'turtle', 1
from sysobjects a, sysobjects b          -- this cross join gives n^2 records
```

Be sure to chose a table where n^2 is greater than the needed records or cross join again and again

Comment: Is there a way to `SELECT` 110 "franklin"s, i.e. specify that I want 110 "duplicates" of franklin (the number is arbitrary)?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but MySQL is perfectly capable of selecting "mock" data and printing it in a table:

```
SELECT "Rufus" AS "Name", "Cat" as "Animal", "3" as "Number of Legs" 
UNION 
SELECT "Franklin", "Turtle", "1" 
UNION 
SELECT "Norm", "Dog", "5";
```

Which would result in:

```
+----------+--------+----------------+
| Name     | Animal | Number of Legs |
+----------+--------+----------------+
| Rufus    | Cat    | 3              |
| Franklin | Turtle | 1              |
| Norm     | Dog    | 5              |
+----------+--------+----------------+
```

Doing this query this way prevents actually having to save information in a temporary table, but I'm not sure if it's the *correct* way of doing things.

Comment: Sidenote: My answer assumes `table` has no data in it. If it does, use Luis' answer.

Comment: Your answer is also "correct"; however, for the situation - with the stipulation you specify in your comment - the other one is going to take the "Accepted". Not an easy choice on my part! +1

Comment: @Thomas That's no problem, I would accept his over mine as well. I simply didn't understand that there was data in the table, I just assumed you wanted to output some fake results. Cheers though!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for Spark SQL, then syntax requires a few extra braces:

```
SELECT 'johny' AS pet, 'human' AS animal_type, 2 AS number_of_legs 
UNION (SELECT 'rufus',    'cat',    3)
UNION (SELECT 'franklin', 'turtle', 1)
UNION (SELECT 'norm',     'dog',    5)
```

OR

```
SELECT pet, animal_type, number_of_legs FROM existing_table
UNION (SELECT 'rufus',    'cat',    3)
UNION (SELECT 'franklin', 'turtle', 1)
UNION (SELECT 'norm',     'dog',    5)
```